# how to: dynamic navigation bar size depending on dynamic image size?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dynamic, height

I've got an image on my page consuming 25% of the width. Now I want the navigation bar on the right of it to have the same height as the image. How do I do that? I would prefer an CSS or JS solution, if possible... And I dont want to use a table...

Thanks in advance!

PS:
The navigation bar is a variation of this:
http://de.selfhtml.org/css/layouts/anzeige/nav_modern.htm

This is a part of the main page:

```
<style type="text/css">
   #Logo {
      position: absolute;
      margin-left: 20px;
      margin-top: 20px;
      width: 25%;
      border: 2px solid black;
   }

   #Nav {
      position: absolute;
      margin-left: 30%;
      margin-top: 20px;
   }

</style>



</head>
<body text="#000000" bgcolor="#ABECEE" link="#FF0000" alink="#FF0000" vlink="#FF0000">

<img src="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" id="Logo"></img>
<div id="Nav"><?php include("navi.html"); ?></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have #Logo's height affecting #Nav's height of they are both absolutely positioned (without using JS). Would something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Spycho/rGHte/) do the trick instead?

#### Update

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Spycho/rGHte/7/) fits the OP's requirements more closely.

Comment: They don't need to be absolute...

Like that, I dont manage to get my navbar next to the image...

Comment: You will only get the navbar next to the image if there is space. that nav bar is too big unless you have a rather high res monitor, like mine :) You could make it so that the menu items appear there if there's space, and if there isn't, only those that don't fit go on to a new line if you want? Or you could make it scrollable.

Comment: my screen is very big, and it still wont work^^

well, could you help me with that? I dont manage to fit the bar to the space available...

Comment: I'm talking [really big](http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=bsd&cs=04&sku=224-8284&~ck=dellSearch&baynote_bnrank=0&baynote_irrank=2)... Drop the width of the img to something smaller and you should be able to get the fiddle to work in a smaller window. Personally, I would go with only wrapping the menu items that don't fit onto a new line rather than all of the nav.

Comment: wow, thanks! that one looks a lot better! Now I only need to fix the flyouts and maybe implement an option to equal the number of menu elements per line... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

am not sure I get you right, but from what I understood you want a scrollbar for the image, so you could do something like this:

```
<html>
    <body>
    <div class="myimage">
    </div>
    </body>
</html>

.myimage
{
    background-image: url('to-my-image');
    overflow-y: scroll;
    /*whatever the width and height of your image*/
    height: 40px;
    width: 50px;
}
```

Comment: no, my image works with this tag: width: 25%;

my navigation bar is next to it, and I want them to have the same height, as the height of the image is automatically reduced or increased to fit to the width...